# Create LI from C# code behind into an ASPX page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an ASPX page with a `asp:BulletedList` control which I would like to populate from code-behind using C#.

Here is my SQL Table (`TBook`):

```
LOCATION
New Rochelle
Purchase
Rye
Scarsdale
White Plains
Yonkers
```

My ASP page looks like this so far:

```
<div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #A7DFFF; background: #DDDDDD;">
        <div style="width: 100%; background: #0181C7; height: 50px; line-height: 50px;">
            <span style="color: #fff;text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #999, 0px 2px 0px #888, 0px 3px 0px #777, 0px 4px 0px #666, 0px 5px 0px #555, 0px 6px 0px #444, 0px 7px 0px #333, 0px 8px 7px #001135;font: 35px 'ChunkFiveRegular';">LOCATIONS</span>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 15px;"></div>
        <asp:BulletedList class="ulLocation" id="ulLocation_selector" runat="server">  
        </asp:BulletedList>
        <!--<ul class="ulLocation" id="ulLocation2_selector" runat="server">
            <li class="liSubLocation active" data-trait-id="9">
                <a href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=12&amp;tags[]=66" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="9">
                    <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
                    <span class="name">New Rochelle</span>
                    <span class="count">6</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="liSubLocation active" data-trait-id="12">
                <a href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=66&amp;tags[]=9" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="12">
                    <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
                    <span class="name">Purchase</span>
                    <span class="count">6</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="liSubLocation" data-trait-id="14">
                <a href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=12&amp;tags[]=14&amp;tags[]=66&amp;tags[]=9" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="14">
                    <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
                    <span class="name">Rye</span>
                    <span class="count">4</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="liSubLocation" data-trait-id="5">
                <a href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=12&amp;tags[]=5&amp;tags[]=66&amp;tags[]=9" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="5">
                    <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
                    <span class="name">Scarsdale</span>
                    <span class="count">6</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="liSubLocation" data-trait-id="3">
                <a href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=12&amp;tags[]=3&amp;tags[]=66&amp;tags[]=9" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="3">
                    <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
                    <span class="name">White Plains</span>
                    <span class="count">5</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="liSubLocation active" data-trait-id="66">
                <a href="/locations/new-york/neighborhoods?tags[]=12&amp;tags[]=9" class="premote trait-link large btn" data-trait-id="66">
                    <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
                    <span class="name">Yonkers</span>
                    <span class="count">6</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>-->
    </div>
```

The C# code so far looks like this:

```
string connectionString="Data Source=myServBook;InitialCatalog=MyDB; UserID=srvdb;" + 
                        "Password=servdbtest0980";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*using(SqlConnection sqlConnection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     string insertStatement="SELECT FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[TBook]";
     SqlCommand sqlCommand=new SqlCommand(insertStatement,sqlConnection);
     /* ADD THE LI HERE */
     /*sqlConnection.Open();
     sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}*/
    }
```

I have the following code which adds the LI based on DataSource:

```
DataTable dt = getData(); //Insert your datasource here

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Attributes.Add("data-trait-id", row["TraitID"].ToString());

        HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
        a.Attributes.Add("data-trait-id", row["TraitID"].ToString());

        HtmlGenericControl span1 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span1.Attributes.Add("class", "name");
        span1.InnerText = row["Name"].ToString();
        a.Controls.Add(span1);

        HtmlGenericControl span2 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span2.Attributes.Add("class", "count");
        span2.InnerText = row["Count"].ToString();
        a.Controls.Add(span2);

        li.Controls.Add(a);
        ulSpecialty_selector.Controls.Add(li);
    }
```

The above code uses a DataSource. How can I modify it so it adds the number of LI based on the number of rows in the table, similar to the commented out HTML code in my ASPX page?

```
Link = "#"
Name = Table Row Value
Count = Table Row Number
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to count how many rows you have? If so you can go something like ...DT.tables[0].Rows.count()

Comment: I want to be able to do the same way on this site: `https://www.airbnb.com/locations/new-york/neighborhoods`. The small white box will be blank, the bold text will be replaced by my Row value and the number on the right will be replaced by the row count number from the table...

Comment: Gotcha, that's a check box list...I'm on my phone right now but I can get on my laptop and send the answer in 10 minutes...until then checkout checkboxlist, you can databind to it and itll work

Comment: Wow... Awesome! Thanks. I will check it out in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with for you, the only problem is that you wanted a number on the right as well, this solution won't do that. However you can use a repeater, that will allow you to have your number to the right. Anyhow this is some idea to get you through till someone gives a better solution...

```
        cblTest.DataSource = "YourDataTableOrDataset";
        cblTest.DataValueField = "YourIDColumnFromYourTable";
        cblTest.DataTextField = "YourColumnName";
        cblTest.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;//Option of vertical
        cblTest.RepeatColumns = 5; //or however many you need i.e how many columns you want to go across before repeating
        cblTest.CssClass = "YourCSSClass"; //for styling the checkboxlist
        cblTest.DataBind();
```